# How do you initialise Select variable in page object model

Tags: java, selenium, dropdown

```
By user_ID = By.name("txtUserID");
By pwd = By.name("txtPassword");
By Login = By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Log In')]");
By dropdownclient = By.xpath("//select[@id='selClientSelect']");

public void select_client()
    {   

        Select client = new Select(dropdownclient);
        client.selectByValue("1");
    }
```

But I am getting error "The constructor `Select(By)` is undefined"

Comment: show please your import of Select class. Plus, Select constructor works with WebElement not with By. Correct your elements initialization so it will solve your problem. For example: Webelement dropdownclient = driver.find(By.xpath("//select[@id='selClientSelect']"));

Comment: I am not using driver here.I have initilizsed other elements like this                     
                By user_ID = By.name("txtUserID");
  By pwd = By.name("txtPassword");
  By Login = By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Log In')]");
  By dropdownclient = By.xpath("//select[@id='selClientSelect']");
  By errorMessage = By.xpath("//div[@id='site-divSimpleDialog']/div/div");

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported Select: `import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;`

You also need to initialize your WebElement before you can pass it into the Select constructor:

```
WebElement dropDownElement = driver.findElement(dropdownClient);
Select client = new Select(dropDownElement);
```

Comment: the problem is that he actually has not initialized his elements, because Select does not work with By abstract class

Comment: Yes, you are correct - we need WebElement instance too.